# i am trying to deploy my project in Netlify but Failed to build site. i don't know whats wrong help me out guys

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, netlify

6:26:26 PM: Build ready to start
6:26:28 PM: build-image version: d7b3dbfb0846505993c9a131894d1858074c90b4 (focal)
6:26:28 PM: build-image tag: v4.10.1
6:26:28 PM: buildbot version: 67e75f1ba713a8213d4b5a8ccf9708af751e2390
6:26:28 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
6:26:28 PM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
6:26:28 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
6:26:28 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
6:26:28 PM: git clone https://github.com/bharathwebdev/Instagram-clone
6:26:28 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/main
6:26:29 PM: Parsing package.json dependencies
6:26:30 PM: Starting build script
6:26:30 PM: Installing dependencies
6:26:30 PM: Python version set to 2.7
6:26:30 PM: Downloading and installing node v16.17.0...
6:26:30 PM: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.17.0/node-v16.17.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
6:26:30 PM: Computing checksum with sha256sum
6:26:30 PM: Checksums matched!
6:26:33 PM: Now using node v16.17.0 (npm v8.15.0)
6:26:33 PM: Started restoring cached build plugins
6:26:33 PM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
6:26:33 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.2, read from environment
6:26:34 PM: Using ruby version 2.7.2
6:26:34 PM: Using PHP version 8.0
6:26:35 PM: No npm workspaces detected
6:26:35 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
6:26:35 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
6:26:35 PM: Installing NPM modules using NPM version 8.15.0
6:26:35 PM: npm WARN config tmp This setting is no longer used.  npm stores temporary files in a special
6:26:35 PM: npm WARN config location in the cache, and they are managed by
6:26:35 PM: npm WARN config     [`cacache`](http://npm.im/cacache).
6:26:35 PM: npm WARN config tmp This setting is no longer used.  npm stores temporary files in a special
6:26:35 PM: npm WARN config location in the cache, and they are managed by
6:26:35 PM: npm WARN config     [`cacache`](http://npm.im/cacache).
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR!
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR! While resolving: react-instagram-embed@3.0.0
6:26:36 PM: Creating deploy upload records
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR! node_modules/react
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.10.4
6:26:37 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1 (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR!     @emotion/react@"^11.10.4" from the root project
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.10.4
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR!       @emotion/styled@"^11.10.4" from the root project
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR!       3 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system)
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR!     3 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system)
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR!   12 more (@emotion/styled, ...)
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR!
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ~0.14.0" from react-instagram-embed@3.0.0
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR! node_modules/react-instagram-embed
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR!   react-instagram-embed@"^3.0.0" from the root project
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR!
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR! node_modules/react
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ~0.14.0" from react-instagram-embed@3.0.0
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR!   node_modules/react-instagram-embed
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR!     react-instagram-embed@"^3.0.0" from the root project
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR!
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR!
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR! See /opt/buildhome/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
6:26:36 PM: npm ERR!     /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2022-09-03T12_56_35_789Z-debug-0.log
6:26:36 PM: Error during NPM install
6:26:36 PM: Build was terminated: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
6:26:37 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
6:26:37 PM: Finished processing build request in 8.800220119s

Answer (score 0):

error suggests installing with --legacy-peer-deps, did you try it?
If not, create a ".npmrc" file in the root folder of the project and paste this line.

```
legacy-peer-deps=true
```